# Error from Rfacebook 'getPage' with since&until

Tags: r

I am using `Rfacebook` version `0.6`.

When I call `getPage` with `since` and `until` dates as following, I get the following error.  What I am doing wrong, or if there's something that need be updated in the package itself?

Note: `<facebook_page_name>`, `<my_app_id>`, `<my_app_secret>` are placeholders for illustration, without using the actual values.

Here are the details:

```
content<-get_fb_data("<facebook_page_name>",since="2016/01/01",until="2016/01/20",condition=2)

get_fb_data<-function(page_name,no_of_records,since_date,until_date,condition)
{

  #get data from facebook page

  library("Rfacebook")

  fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="<my_app_id>",    app_secret="<my_app_secret>",
extended_permissions = FALSE)

  if (condition == 1)
  {
    content<-getPage(page_name, fb_oauth, no_of_records, feed = TRUE)
  } 
  else
  {
    since_date<-paste(since_date,"00:00:00 IST",sep=" ")
    until_date<-paste(until_date,"23:59:59 IST",sep=" ")

    from_value<-as.numeric(as.POSIXct(since_date)) 
    to_value<-as.numeric(as.POSIXct(until_date))

    content<-getPage(page_name, fb_oauth, 
                         since = from_value, 
                         until = to_value, 
                         feed = TRUE)
  }

  return(content)
}
```

Error displayed:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(since) : 'origin' must be supplied

Per debug, this is from function `as.Date` called in `getPage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
library("Rfacebook")

fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="<my_app_id>", app_secret="<my_app_secret>",
                    extended_permissions = FALSE)



get_fb_data <- function(page_name, no_of_records, since_date, 
                        until_date, condition){
    if (condition == 1){
        content<-getPage(page_name, fb_oauth, no_of_records, feed = TRUE)
    } else{
        content <- getPage(page_name, fb_oauth, 
                           since = since_date, 
                           until = until_date, 
                           feed = TRUE)
    }

    content
}

content <- get_fb_data("humansofnewyork",
                       since_date="2016/01/01",
                       until_date="2016/01/2",
                       condition=2)
```

I do not really understand, why you are trying to change date format - it's unnecessary. What is more, you have a syntax error, because `else` should be written after `}` closing `if`. You shouldn't also load packages inside your function. What for loading it each time? The same with your `fb_oauth`.

Comment: When I passed the dates directly, I remember getting an error that the dates should be in a format recognizable by strtodate().  Miraculously, I don't get that error anymore.  The syntax error of if-else was due to a copy-paste mistake.  The library and fbAuth calls inside the function were just for illustration and does not reflect the actual code, but thanks for the suggestions.